# Rest API React and AXIOS in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to parse Rest API resposnes with JSON. But when I use AXIOS in functional compoment it returns first empty array and then exact api response.data / after render. So return functions returns empty array but in the fact the data is there but after rendering

The api response

```
{
"eventId": "3c6a12e3-ac96-4f9d-9d26-7c7a6c730198",
"organizerId": "23a41cd1-e60e-41ff-b5d3-13815ed9b3a9",
"eventDate": "2021-11-28T14:14:16.191167",
"eventPlayerLimit": 10,
"eventFee": 0.0,
"playerSubscriptions": [
{
"subscriptionId": "2616720f-7106-429e-89f6-97be51dfbaf6",
"subscriptionPaymentDone": "true",
"subscriptionDate": "2021-11-28T14:14:16.217146",
"subscriptionApproved": "true",
"eventTitle": "Title",
"eventDate": "2021-11-28T14:14:16.191167",
"playerId": "a04d3ca2-af3d-4655-9eaf-6a892efe2dab",
"playerEmail": "player@player.com"
}
],
"title": "Title"
}
```

And the component body

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Card, Button, Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import axios from "axios";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

function EventsDetails () {
  const [eventDetails, setEventDetails] = useState([])
    let {id} = useParams();
    function getEvents() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/events/"+id)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
                setEventDetails(data)
            });
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getEvents();
    },[])
    console.log(id);
    console.log(eventDetails);
        return (
            <Card className={"border border-dark bg-dark text-white"}>
                <Card.Header><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} /> Events</Card.Header>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Table bordered hover striped variant="dark">
                        <thead>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <th>Event Date</th>
                            <th>Event title</th>
                            <th>Localization</th>
                            <th>Payment Fee</th>
                            <th>Subscribed users</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {eventDetails.length === 0 ?
                            <tr align="center">
                                <td colSpan="6">No events available</td>
                            </tr> :
                            <tr align="center">
                            <td colSpan="6">{eventDetails.length}</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
)
}export default EventsDetails
```

Console log
[image: Console LOG]

Comment: What is your question? This is expected behavior: the request is asynchronous and doesn't block the component render

Comment: when you call an api the data are not available until the http request is fulfilled. For this reason there is a moment in which data are not available (first render). When data come from the API call another render is done with the eventDetail state filled in with the response.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior.  Your first `console.log` is being executed before the state update.  The function is not returning an empty array, you're seeing the default state from `const [eventDetails, setEventDetails] = useState([])` being logged.

Answer (score 1):

Initially on the page load... you dont have data because API takes some moment before it respond with data and meanwhile your component already rendered with empty array i.e no data...

at some moment later the API comes back with data and update the state but you've already seen a component without required data...

**So a way around it is**

You put a component/content/loader to be shown while you're waiting for API to give you data to be shown... and when that data comes you take back the loader component and show that data from API

With codes it could be something as below

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Card, Button, Table} from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import axios from "axios";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

function EventsDetails () {
  const [eventDetails, setEventDetails] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    let {id} = useParams();
    function getEvents() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/events/"+id)
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
                setEventDetails(data)
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getEvents();
    },[])
    
    ....//removed for brevity

    return <>{isLoading ? <DisplayLoader /> : <DisplayData />}</>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Sometimes I have undefined errors. Now I understand why. My function is called on every render. So I added Loader